I live outside of Canada and Don't Have a Canadian bank account. Can I still cash the cheque from the cra for filing my tax returns
I am a Canadian living abroad in Europe and I got a cheque from the cra for doing my taxes. I closed my Canadian bank account when I left. It is currently sitting with family back home. Is there any way to access this money as it's a substantial amount where I am living now?
I thought of maybe endorsing it over to my dad but I'm not sure I can do that without being there to physically sign it. And mailing it isn't an option because of the Canada post strike.
I also decided to try and sign up for an online bank in hopes that I can cash it via picture, but am still waiting to hear a response from the bank in question.
I called my old bank to see if I can re-open my account but they said I'd have to come in as they couldn't find my name in their system.
If the online banking doesn't work out I'm absolutely lost on this, I could really use this money as I am trying to get citizenship in my current country which is getting expensive.

They could have deposited money directly to your bank account in most countries.  I don't know how to change it after you've received a cheque, but maybe call them.  https://www.tpsgc-pwgsc.gc.ca/recgen/dd/etranger-abroad-eng.html

Does the new country not have banks?
